# Как отредактировать страницу предосмотра колонки в категориях в Админке BackPack Laravel Php

Tags: php, laravel

не могу никак понять как правильно редактировать страницу предпросмотра в админке BackPack Laravel, суть в том что в заполнении формы поля отображаются на русском языке в принципе так как я их прописал в коде, а в предпросмотре не заполненные поля вовсе не отображаются, а название полей на Английском, вот в чём заключается вопрос, как правильно отредактировать страницу Предпросмотра. Документацию консультировал, но там нет понятного решения по крайней мере для меня

Вот код страницы добавления формы

```
 protected function setupCreateOperation()

{
    CRUD::setValidation(StoreRequest::class);

    //CRUD::setFromDb(); // fields

    $this->crud->addFields([
        [
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Название'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'slug',
            'label' => 'Slug'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'category',
            'label' => 'Категория'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'meta',
            'label' => 'Доп. данные',
            'type' => 'table'
        ]
    ]);
}
 
protected function setupUpdateOperation()
{
    $this->setupCreateOperation();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел описание всего процесса на отдельной странице в документации BackPack https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operation-show

В любом случае вот пример кода который решил мою проблему

```
     public function setupShowOperation()
        {
            $this->crud->set('show.setFromDb', false);
    
            $this->crud->addColumns([
            [
                'name' => 'name',
                'label' => 'Название'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'slug',
                'label' => 'Slug'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'category',
                'label' => 'Категория'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'meta',
                'label' => 'Доп. данные',
                'type' => 'table'
            ]
         ]);
        }
```